# Getting existing rows to export using Kafka Export Connector in VoltDB

Tags: voltdb

I am working on a solution to migrate from an older schema to a newer schema betwen two VoltDB instances. I was looking at The Kafka Export Connector and Kafka Import and the ability to write procedures to convert data from older schema to a new schema is just what I needed. The only problem is I have is with this - Export data is generated whenever a SQL INSERT is executed on an export table inside a VoltDB partition. How do I get all the existing rows in the older schema to start exporting ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use  *INSERT INTO stream_name ... SELECT ... FROM table_name* to move your data.  See the [docs](https://docs.voltdb.com/UsingVoltDB/sqlref_insert.php) for more information on this form of INSERT.

Disclosure: I work for VoltDB.